# Docker hub Is possible to pass price plan from account to organization

Tags: dockerhub

I have created multiple containers and make them private by paying a plan, but now I want to set an organization with their teams and users to grant access to every container created, but I noticed that I only can give permissions to the containers created inside that organization, so the repositories I pay are useless, Is there a way to pass the plan to the organization instead the personal account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On docker hub, on settings, on the bottom exists a button that let you change an account to an organization if you give another personal account but when I try it always throws and error that says that the personal account is part of a group, but that personal account is not part of a group, also I sended an email to support@docker.com and tell them my problem and they said that I need to cancel the plan because the plans are not transferable and later pay the plan for the organization, in resume for this moment you can't transfer the plan from a personal account to an organization.